# Display WordPress search results on same page as search form

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I have a search form within a WordPress page template.  I'd like to show results on the same page as the search form, but evrything I try doesnt seem to work.  I've tried replacing the input name `s` with `search` as to bypass WordPress' default query, leaving the action field blank as well as using the current page permalink, both `get_permalink` and `echo esc_url( get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'Page_Template' ) ) )`, and writing a custom loop.  Everything I try seems to either throw a 404 page not found error, or redirects to the home page.

Here is the modified search form and loop that I am using:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'Page_Template' ) ) )?>">
    <label for="s" class="assistive-text">Search</label>
    <input type="text" class="field" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</form>


<?php
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST[ 'search' ] ) ) {
        // run search query
        query_posts( array(
            's' => $_REQUEST[ 'search' ],
            'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
        ) );

        // loop
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) :
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a href="'.the_permalink().'">'.the_title().'</a>';
            echo '</li>';
        endwhile; endif;

        // return to original query
        wp_reset_query();
    }?>
```

This example throws a 404 page not found error.

Any help would be much appreciated, I've been at this for a few hours and cant seem to get it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wich URL does the `action` point at?